# Cocoapods complete custom prefix header file, using prefix_header_file only appends to default content

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to use OpenCV from a pod in a subspec on a framework that I'm working on and that requires adding a prefix header file. Since Cocoapods provides a property named `prefix_header_file` that should be trivial. But the problem I have is that what happens is that cocoapods appends the content of the provided file after some default content. This does not work because the opencv headers **needs to be included before the objective c parts**.

I have tried to add a post_install to the subspec but that does not seem to get executed (not mentioned in the docs so probably dropped support for that) and I have looked at the script_phase but that only executes on build time I think. I dont want the users of the framework to have to add some post_install to their Podfiles. Someone must have had this issue before?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.6.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.6
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
       Xcode : 11.3.1 (11C504)
         Git : git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 20c4d13a7bbfb4a1871705bc38fe0266eed3841a
               trunk -  @ fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

#### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now with latest Cocoapods being v1.9 it is not possible

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9625